# Javascript and Same Origin Policy in Windows .chm

Tags: javascript, chm

We are using Windows-HTML-Help (.chm) for delivering context-specific help to for our software to our customers.

Just recently I implemented a js-enabled way to change the behaviour of the help file.

The page on display has an iframe which loads a file from the local disk. This file contains this lines:

```
if (self != top) {
  window.parent.showHelp();
}
```

Obviously, there is a function in the main page that does some css magic to display specific content.

Now, using this works fine when having all files on the local disk of the developer machine (this seems obvious). Additionally, it also works fine when I use the .chm from a locally attached disk (like V:\ -> \\domain\share).

BUT calling the .chm from \\domain\share\abc.chm results in a "permission denied error" for the called function.

I would understand perfectly if the .chm and the included .htm file would reside on different disks or domains for that matter. But it's completely the same space - just in one occasion called via UNC directly and one from an attached disk.

Just for the sake of argument: HHRestrictions and ItssRestrictions are set to be an complete open door with MaxAllowedZone and URLAllowList.

I would be happy if somebody had an idea as to how this different behaviour could be compensated for.

Thanks!

Kai

Comment: I would like to suggest you to use HHREG even if you're sure to have done everything right for your MaxAllowedZone and URLAllowList. http://www.helpandmanual.com/products_hhreg.html and please check with MJ's Diagnostics from (http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/mj-s-diagnostics). See report listing examples in the lower part of the page.

Comment: Work other CHM's from \\domain\share\foobar.chm?

Comment: @help-info.de , yeah, the .chm itself works perfectly. HHREG and MJ used, the HHREG settings were checked again and MJ shows every setting and DLL is in working order.

Comment: only a thought - what's about 32 and 64 bit Java?. See: http://programming.nullanswer.com/question/30105874 and you may have a look for one more cross check at: http://tenbulls.co.uk/2014/02/11/read-your-old-chm-files-from-network-storage-on-windows-8/